# Cannot store value into vector struct

Tags: c++, string, vector

So I'm Trying to store a string in this struct:

```
struct node{
    std::string name;
};
```

by (roughly) doing this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // ... other code ...

    std::vector<char> chars;
    chars.push_back('n');

    std::vector<node> nodes;
    for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        nodes.push_back(node());
        for(auto ch : chars) {
            switch(ch) {
                 case 'n': {
                     nodes[i].name = argv[i];
                     break;
                 }
             }
         }
     }

     // ... other code ...

     for(auto n : nodes) {
         std::cout << n.name << '\n';
     }
     return 0;
}
```

The whole program compiles and runs but without the output of n.name. It seems like it is only setting nodes[i]'s values within its switch block but I'm not sure why this is. When debugging and looking at values in gdb, nodes[i]'s values are set within that switch block's case however, when I look at the whole array (print nodes) it shows I have not set the name field within the struct. When I leave the switch block entirely (on a new iteration of the loop) and look at the value of that node (node[0] for example) I don't see the name value set there either.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I'm new to C++ (familiar with C) but it wouldn't make sense that either the argv[i] (which gets casted into a c++ string AND is declared outside the switch's scope) or the new node that gets pushed back at the beginning of the loop iteration goes out of scope.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is `chars`?

Comment: That comes from the "other" parts of the code that drive the switch logic. Its a vector of characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, it was in the indexing of the nodes in my original code (not shown here).

Answer (score 2):

If that's your actual code, there's nothing wrong with it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct node{
    std::string name;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // ... other code ...

    std::vector<char> chars;
    chars.push_back('n');

    std::vector<node> nodes;
    for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        nodes.push_back(node());
        for(auto ch : chars) {
            switch(ch) {
                 case 'n': {
                     nodes[i].name = argv[i];
                     break;
                 }
             }
         }
     }

     // ... other code ...

     for(auto n : nodes) {
         std::cout << n.name << '\n';
     }
     return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run that, I get the expected output:

```
pax$ ./testprog a b c
./testprog
a
b
c
```

I therefore have to assume that's *not* your actual code, especially since the act of creating a one-element vector containing `'n'` and then operating on something else  based on every element in that vector being `'n'` seems to be rather, err, ... strange (that's about as diplomatic as I can get).

My suggestion would be to strip your code down to the smallest one that exhibits the problem and post that. It's hard enough debugging code when we *have* the source, there's little reason to make it harder by posting *different* code :-)

---

Without seeing the actual code, we can *still* make some suggestions on how you can discern where the problem lies.

First, where you assign the name, output it to ensure it's set correctly at that point (add the second line below):

```
nodes[i].name = argv[i];
std::cout << "Added #" << i << " with value '" << nodes[i].name << "'\n";
break;
```

Second, make sure the control vector is doing what you expect (add the second line below). There should be one `n` line per argument:

```
for(auto ch : chars) {
    std::cout << "Control ch is '" << ch << "'\n";
    switch(ch) {
```

Third, check the vector size before printing, it should be non-zero (add first line below):

```
std::cout << "Vector size is " << n.size() << "\n";
for(auto n : nodes) {
    std::cout << n.name << '\n';
}
```

You should also output this as you're *expanding* the vector (add third line below):

```
for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
    nodes.push_back(node());
    std::cout << "Vector size on build is " << n.size() << "\n";
```

---

The output of those debug statements will hopefully give you a clearer picture as to what your data is at various stages of the code, and allow you to target the problem area.